# Numbering of chapters and sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am writing my master thesis. I just started working on LaTeX. I am writing the first chapter. I used `\chapter{Introduction}`, but when I make a section using `\section{abcd}`,
the section number is 0.2  even though the chapter number is 1. I want the section numbers to be "chapter number"."Section number" (e.g., 1.1 for the first section of first chapter).

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{introduction}
here goes my text......
\section{motivation}

\chapter{background}  % corrected typo: \chatper{background}

\end{document}
```

I want the chapter number to be 1 for the first chapter not 0, and the section number for the first section of first chapter to be 1.1.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete example code that reproduces the problem. Without that it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: Typesetting your example I get "Chapter 1 Introduction" and the section is numbered 1.1; then "Chapter 2 Background" (after correcting the typo). You probably have something else that causes the trouble. Oh! I almost forgot to say "Welcome to TeX.SX!"

Comment: Same here, it works fine (after correcting the typo). Are you sure you are telling us everything?

Comment: Perhaps you have seen the wrong number in the table of contents. The table of contents and the other lists (figures, tables) need two or more LaTeX runs to get synchronized until LaTeX does not generate "rerun" warnings.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Even in one LaTeX pass the example given is numbered fine...

Comment: If the first version that is compiled with LaTeX does not have `\chapter`, then the section is numbered `0.1`. Then `\chapter` is added, but the next LaTeX run still shows section `0.1` in the table of contents, but `1.1` in the text.

Comment: After checking those helpful comments, if the problems still remain, please, are you sure that your `report.cls` is the original one? Maybe somebody edited it.